WPF Binding a 2 property Class to Combobox in DataGridTemplateColumn
I have a datagrid with the binding set to a DataTable which may have 1, or more, columns with a 2 property class. The 2 properties are a List of strings and a string. Attempting to bind the ItemsSource and SelectedValue of a Combobox to those properties has been a real challenge for me (I'm a novice at this WPF stuff). I have searched for, found, read, and tried many solutions others have posted but none have worked for me.
I have a small example project for this, but I don't see a way to post files here. SO here are the relevant sections of code. First, the Class:
    public class PropList
    {
        public string CurrentValue;
        public List<string> Values;

        public PropList(string val, List<string>list)
        {
            CurrentValue = val;
            Values = list;
        }
    }

The columns in the DataTable is created with this:
clm = theTable.Columns.Add("The_Model_List", typeof(PropList));

The DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn event has this:
            if (e.PropertyType == typeof(PropList))
            {
                var col = new PropListDataGridTemplateColumn
                {
                    Header = e.PropertyName,
                    ColumnName = e.PropertyName,
                    CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("PropListDataTemplate")
                };
                e.Column = col;
                return;
            }

The PropListDataGridTemplateColumn is defined as such:
//as found on stackoverflow
   public class PropListDataGridTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
   {
       public string ColumnName
       {
           get;
           set;
       }
       protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
       {
           // The DataGridTemplateColumn uses ContentPresenter with your DataTemplate.
           var cp = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
           // Reset the Binding to the specific column. The default binding is to the DataRowView.
           cp.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.ColumnName));
           return cp;
       }
       protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
       {
           // The DataGridTemplateColumn uses ContentPresenter with your DataTemplate.
           var cp = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
           // Reset the Binding to the specific column. The default binding is to the DataRowView.
           cp.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.ColumnName));
           return cp;
       }

   }

Finally, in the xaml:
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="PropListDataTemplate" DataType="DataRowView">
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
;;;other stuff
            <DataGrid x:Name="PropData" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EntityData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" 
                  SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Extended"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" CellEditEnding="PropData_CellEditEnding"/>


Edited to add: The DataGrid ItemsSource is bound to the DataTable (EntityData in the VM). The Column to show the PropList class is bound correctly, but I cannot get the 2 properties bound to the ComboBox's ItemsSource and SelectedItem properties

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

After struggling with this for a month I have learned of a different way to approach this. If this ever gets answered, I may revisit it, but the new direction is working satisfactorily.

I'm still curious about this issue. Here is a link to a previous question about the same issue. It was asked a bit better than I did and it has a link to a Demo project which exhibits the problem. His solution, however, I cannot get to work...even in his demo. link
